# Check if a number in a string contains a valid year in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a the following string and need to ensure that the number in the string is a valid year. So in this case 2014.

```
var notesField = "Payment for the month ending 30 Nov 2014";
char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
string[] text = notesField.Split(
                          whitespace,
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                          );
```

Comment: What is a valid year, 3683? What if the string is `"Payment for the month ending 30 Nov"`? Is 30 a valid year, how do you detect the year?

Comment: what do you consider to be a valid year?

Comment: Any integer could be considered a valid year. Please be more specific.

Comment: what about multiple valid years? "Payment 2015 for the 2011th month ending 30 Nov 2014" ?

Comment: What about the string `"Bob gave Alice 2014 cows"`?

Comment: What about other ways of writing the date? "Payment for the month ending 30.11.2014", should that be considered a valid year also? What part of it is the actual year?

Comment: OP just quit his job. Jokes aside, you need to formally define what's a valid year. I guess the reason you're asking is that you haven't thought about it yet? I'd see where these noteFields come from and how they differ from each other. But keep in mind, no matter how good you solve it today, tomorrow it'll come back to haunt you...

Comment: I remember doing something similar back in '09

Comment: @DavidG: so last year bob gave alice some cows? ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well last year it was only 2013 cows, I think it was in the evening, possibly 2100 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to find or validate year in this way is never recommended but if you are sure that there will be exactly one four digits word in the sentence then you can use regex match like below.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}");
        Match match = regex.Match("Payment for the month ending 30 Nov 2014");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

working fiddle is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V6Ta2Q)

Answer (score 4):

You can't - any positive integer is (in theory) a potentially valid year. You need to come up with a sensible definition of "what a valid year", an example might be "a 4 digit number between 2005 and 2020" (e.g. if you only expect to see dates in the recent past or near future).

This of course doesn't handle the `"Bob gave Alice 2014 cows"` case - to fix this you could try to be clever and do some basic date parsing (e.g. recognising the `"30 Nov"` part of your string), however in general **this is a hard problem to solve** - consider what could happen if your system came across someone called "June"?

The best way to handle this is to place restrictions on your input to make validation easier. Ideally you would provide a separate control specifically for entering dates, however if you are for some reason stuck with text input you could just look for strings of the form `"Payment for the month ending {Day} {Month} {Year}"` - the more relaxed you are with the input you expect the harder time you are going to have trying to parse & validate it.

Comment: He could specify a list of supported/searched datetime-formats. Then he could try to parse all substrings starting with the space-indexes with the length of each supported format-string(f.e. `"dd MMM yyyy"`) with `DateTime.TryParseExact`. If one returns `true` he has found a valid `DateTime`.