# How to determine if a year was passed into System.Datetime.TryParse

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert text passed by a user into a datetime. I know the culture of the user and so I'm passing in:

```
if (System.DateTime.TryParse(enteredValue, userCultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out newDateTimeValue)
{
  //do something
}
```

That's all working fine, but the "Do Something" section needs to add 1 year to the newDateTimeValue if the user didn't pass in a year.

e.g. if the user enters (with Australia Culture Code):

- 26/02/2018 - return result of DateTime.TryParse (26 Feb 2018)
- 06 2018 - return result of DateTime.TryParse (1 June 2018)
- 26/02 - return result of Datetime.TryParse + 1 year (26 Feb 2019)
- 26 Feb - return result of Datetime.TryParse + 1 year (26 Feb 2019)

How do I work out if the user passed in a year or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a number in a string contains a valid year in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501032/check-if-a-number-in-a-string-contains-a-valid-year-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @JohnWu: This one is actually much easier, because the input should parse as a date (can't have other fluff thrown in)

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah, I only care if the input does parse as a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending your default year, and if that fails, parse the original input:

```
int defaultYear = (DateTime.Now.Year + 1);
bool ok = DateTime.TryParse(input + " " + defaultYear.ToString(), out result)
       || DateTime.TryParse(input, out result);
```

It worked on all the test cases I tried, but there's probably some unusual format that will work with `TryParse` but break with a space-separated year.

(Naturally you can pass your extra `cultureInfo` and `dateTimeStyle` arguments, I left those out for brevity)

Comment: Ok this is a much better approach than my answer +1.

Answer (score -2):

So I did a quick test and it seems that if no year is provided, the current year will be used. Thus, you need to figure out if the entered date has the current year and if it does not, then advance it. Below is an example.

```
DateTime parsedResult;
string entry = "26 Feb";
if(DateTime.TryParse(entry, new CultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedResult))
{
    if (!entry.Contains(DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() &&
        !entry.Contains(DateTime.Today.ToString("yy")))
    {
        // This means the entry had no year
        DateTime advanced = parsedResult.AddYears(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of Michael Hudson's and suffers the same problem of being unable to distinguish two-digit years from other date parts

Comment: what if entry contained a year that is not this year? e.g. the user entered 26 Feb 2008

Comment: Actually no it will not because "18 Feb" does not have year and "18/02/18" can be taken care of simply through substringing. The important part is the idea that it defaults to current year.

Comment: @Greg Then the user has entered a year and the `TryParse` method will not default it to the current year. Please read the code carefully.

Comment: Actually this one is buggier than Michael's was.

Comment: @BenVoigt why is it buggy (let alone buggier)? I did tests and it passes. What test case are you speaking of?

Comment: @CodingYoshi: The one Greg gave you.  And the fact that it does the same thing for `18/02` and `18/02/18` when the question requires distinguishing them.

Comment: 18/02 still doesn't work as 18 = year 18. Code is buggy because if you copy and paste it, it doesn't compile (needs more brackets)

Comment: @Greg "18/02" was not one of your test cases. That actually does not even parse because most likely it is not a valid format for Australian dates (another requirement you have). If it was, it would parse and the current year would be used. If you enter a valid Australian format, all test cases will pass. "One bracket missing...", Yes added it but seriously if you need help, then "is adding a bracket" too much work for  you? Be considerate.

Comment: @BenVoigt read my comment above. As for `18/02/18`, the code works.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - I didn't ask the question but I'm pretty sure they wanted more than just the 4 dates in the example to work. 18/02 certainly does parse for Australian dates (dd/mm = 18 Feb 2018) but won't have the year added.

Comment: @greg no it does not parse. Try it out. Sorry I did not mean to say one of "your" requirement. Yes you are not the asker.

Comment: ` DateTime parsedResult;
 DateTime.TryParse("18/02", new CultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedResult);
 parsedResult.Dump();` The result in linqpad is 18 Feb 2018

Comment: @CodingYoshi: The question does include a test case of `26/02` which with your code will fail in 2026, in the exact same way that `18/02` fails today.  It is true that none of the test cases in the question showed a two-digit year.  But even if you exclude those, you're doing the wrong thing for every date that contains a year other than this year.  And in 11 months, you'll also be doing the wrong thing for all the test cases in the question.

Comment: @greg I am using VS 2015 and "18/02" does not parse.

Comment: @benvoigt "18/02" or "26/02" will not even parse. Perhaps they are not valid formats for `en-AU`

Comment: @CodingYoshi: With `en-AU` the problem appears with `"02/18"` and `"18/02/18"`